# Naming a new phenomenon

Tags: isotopic

Hi I am facing a problem at the moment. In a paper I want to name areas that have the same isotopy. For example, areas with the same air pressure are called isobars. So these areas should be called isoisotopes. Is it possible to simply introduce such a term? And if so, how should the name be defined?

[image]